# Add attributs in Product using woocommrece API

Tags: .net, api, woocommerce-rest-api

when I create the attribute for the product from the API woocommerce , the attribute does not appear on the page of my site wordpress, so I have to refresh the publication for the product manually please any help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOigT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REHn2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First If you have attributes already created in attributes section Woocommerce.You
   can update by this PUT:- http:/example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/123
   BODY:

   {
   "attributes": [
   {
   "id": 4, //Example: color's ID
   "options": "white"
   }
   ]
   }
2. If attributes are not present in the attributes section, please create the attributes and assign to the products.You can create attributes in this way.
   POST:- /wp-json/wc/v3/products/attributes

   BODY:

   {
   "name": "Color",
   "slug": "pa_color",
   "type": "select",
   "order_by": "menu_order",
   "has_archives": true
   }